# Redireccionar desde Login en html

Tags: javascript, html, formularios, login

estoy intentando hacer un login en html y que me valide si el usuario y contraseña están correctos con un javascript (por el momento solo veo si usuario y contraseña son iguales), y dependiendo de si están correctos o no que me redirija a una página u otra, el problema es que no he logrado hacer un script que me funcione, el ingreso de datos lo tengo dentro de un form que queda de esta manera:

```
<div class="container">
  <form method="POST" name="formLogin" action="logeado.html" onsubmit="login(userName,password)">
          USERNAME<br>
          <input type="text" name="userName" placeholder="Nombre de usuario"><br>
          PASSWORD<br>
          <input type="text" name="password" placeholder="Contraseña">
          <br>
          <input type="submit" name="btnLogin" value="Ingresar" onsubmit="login">
   </form>
</div>
```

Es algo simple pero solo lo quiero hacer funcionar, el tema es que si username y contraseña son iguales quiero que me redirija a "logeado.html", en caso contrario quiero que se quede en la pag actual que es "login.html" y me mande una alerta de error. Estoy usando visual code con html5. Espero que me puedan ayudar, muchas gracias!

Comment: agrega la función que haces para validar si no no sabemos que mas pasa

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Depende del método que uses pero la lógica seria la misma: Supongamos
>   que uses php:

```
<?php require_once('conn.php'); // aca se requiere el archivo de conexion

    // aca verificamos que las variables post tengan algun tipo de contenido
    if (isset($_POST['userName']) AND isset($_POST['password'])) {
        // realizamos la consulta a la base de datos y pedimos que nos seleccione todo de la tabla que conetnga tanto el usuario O el password
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM USUARIOS WHERE usuario = '".$_POST['userName']."' OR password = '".$_POST['password']."'";
        $con = mysqli_query($conx, $sql);
        $ls = mysqli_fetch_assoc($con); 

        // VALIDACIONES
        if ($_POST['userName'] == $ls['usuario'] AND $_POST['password'] == $ls['contra']) {
            //si usuario que viene del formulario es igual al usuario que traemos de la consulta son iguales Y password del formulario es igual al password de la tabla 
            // si los datos son correctos iniciamos seccion y lo dirigimos la pagina objetivo
            session_start();
            header('location: paginaobjetivo.html');

        }elseif ($_POST['userName'] != $ls['usuario'] AND $_POST['password'] == $ls['contra']) {
            // si el suario del formulario NO es igual al de la tabla Y password del formulario es igual al password de la tabla 
            echo "Tiene un error en el usuario verifique la informacion";
        }elseif ($_POST['userName'] == $ls['usuario'] AND $_POST['password'] != $ls['contra']) {
            // si el suario del formulario es igual al de la tabla Y password del formulario NO es igual al password de la tabla 
            echo "El password es erroneo verifique la informacion";
        }

    }
?>
```

Esto te puede seguir de ejemplo para hacerlo.

Comment: La idea es ayudarlo, no hacerle el feo. Por eso supuse el uso de php.